Getting "Unauthorized" error when trying to renew Microsoft Graph API subscription via C#/.NET
Currently trying to renew a Graph API subscription programmatically. I have double checked to ensure that the client id, subscription id, client secret, and tenant id are all correct but I get the following error when running my code:

Result: Failed to renew subscription with subscription id IvyRehab.Workday.Automations.Functions.Services.GraphCredentials
Exception: Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Operation: Update; Exception: [Status Code: Unauthorized; Reason: Unauthorized; Message : Subscription does not belong to application.]

Here is the code I am trying to run
public async Task RenewSubscription(Subscription subscription)
{
    if (subscription.ExpirationDateTime is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(subscription.ExpirationDateTime));

    try
    {
        await graphServiceClient.Subscriptions[_graphCredentials.SubscriptionId].PatchAsync(subscription);
        _logger.LogInformation("Subscription has been renewed to {newDate}", subscription.ExpirationDateTime.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.LogError(exception, "Failed to renew subscription with subscription id {subscriptionId}", _graphCredentials);
    }
}

I have User.Read and Subscription.Read.All permissions, both enabled in the Azure Portal API permissions.
What do I need to adjust here?
I've tried adjusting permissions, setting up an access key, etc.
I can pull information regarding the subscription and other entities such as users, but I only run into this issue when trying to patch the expiration date.
EDIT 9/27/24
I attempted to retrieve all subscriptions associated with the credentials I provide and I get an empty list in return.
 public class TestRenewal
 {
     private readonly ILogger<TestRenewal> _logger;
     private readonly IGraphSubscriptionService _graphSubscriptionService;
     private readonly IUserService _userService;
     private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

     public TestRenewal(
         ILogger<TestRenewal> logger,
         IGraphSubscriptionService graphSubscriptionService,
         IUserService userService,
         IOptions<GraphCredentials> graphCredentials)
     {
         _logger = logger;
         _graphSubscriptionService = graphSubscriptionService;
         _userService = userService;

         var credentials = graphCredentials?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(graphCredentials));
         var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
             credentials.TenantId,
             credentials.ClientId,
             credentials.ClientSecret
         );

         _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
 }

     [Function("Function")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
     {
         try
         {
             _logger.LogInformation("Getting subscriptions");
             var result = await _graphServiceClient.Subscriptions.GetAsync();
             _logger.LogInformation("Subscriptions retrieved");
             _logger.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
             return new OkObjectResult(result);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to fetch subscriptions.");
             return new OkObjectResult("");
         }
     }
 }

Logs:
[2024-09-27T15:13:41.915Z] {"Value":[],"AdditionalData":{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions"},"BackingStore":{"ReturnOnlyChangedValues":false,"InitializationCompleted":true},"OdataCount":null,"OdataNextLink":null}
[2024-09-27T15:13:43.914Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.SubscriptionCollectionResponse'.

I have double checked the credentials and they are all correct.
Does this have to do with where this subscription lives? This is a subscription I created a few days ago. It is an entra partner topic, see screenshots.


EDIT 9/30/24
Per a suggestion from Md Farid Uddin Kiron I ran a get all subscriptions, it returned nothing. I tried creating a subscription using code and that showed up just fine. I then met with a colleague and he ran a query in graph explorer that returned both the subscription created in the portal and the one created with my code, that revealed that the subscription created in the portal was actually associated with the Client Id of the Azure portal, not any Client IDs specific to me or my applications. So it appears at this time that if I want to renew subscriptions with code then the subscription needs to first be created with code as well.

I'm afraid that we didn't understand this API correctly, let's see the api permission section in api document, there's no User.Read and Subscription.Read.All required. By the way, the erroor message indicates that you used a wrong subscription id, so that I think we could call the list api which requires your API permissions first to get the subscriptions ahead. Then use that id, and correct

API permissions to test the update API again, for user type, it shall be user User.Read.All User.Read.All User.Read.All

First make sure, if you are doing that for correct application, because, If the subscription was originally created by another Azure AD app or user, you won't be able to update or renew it with your current app. Subscriptions are tightly coupled to the app that created them. You'll need to ensure that the app (and client credentials) you're using to renew the subscription is the same one that was used to create it. So what I would do is, I would first try to extent the subscription using portal once it works fine then I would sure more confident that issue belongs to code.

@TinyWang I tested out your suggestions, the credentials are correct but  I get no result, just an empty list. See edits above.
Am I using the wrong method to update the subscription, given where it lives?

The List Api already gave you the result, there's no subscription assiated to the aad application. Just like what Kiron said subscriptions are tightly coupled to the app that created them.

It is a subscription I created in the Azure portal using the same user info I am now. I can already go in the same login for the portal and extend the subscription manually and it works.

Did some testing using the Get All suggestion and Graph Explorer. Turns out when I create the subscription in the portal it is created using the Client ID and credentials of the Azure Portal, not my specific application.
So it appears if I want to adjust the expiration date of the subscription it needs to be a subscription created via code as opposed to in the portal.
